# Safari won't let me type in Flash form

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, safari

I made a flash website with a contact form, which works perfectly in FireFox, IE and Chrome on my pc. However, in Safari I can't seem to type in any textfield; and on Android, I sowehow can only type capital letters (basically capslock is on and it won't let me change to lower case).

I'm suspecting the problem lies entirely within Flash, since sending an email does work just fine. Searching here or on Google doesn't get me to anything related.

Any tips?

**Here is my code:**

*FormScript.as (this is an external .as file called from my main .as file)*

```
//***All imports, vars, etc***

function submit(e:MouseEvent):void {

    //Check to see if any of the fields are empty       
        if(yourName.text == "" || fromEmail.text == "" ||
            yourSubject.text == "" ||yourMsg.text == "" ) {
            valid.text = "All fields must be filled";
        }

    //Check if you're using a valid email address       
        else if(!checkEmail(fromEmail.text)) {
            valid.text = "Please fill in an existing email";
        } 

        else { 
            valid.text = "Verzenden.."; 
            var emailData:String = 
            "name=" + yourName.text +
            "&from=" + fromEmail.text +
            "&subject=" + yourSubject.text +
            "&msg=" + yourMsg.text;

            var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(emailData);
            urlVars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            urlRequest.data = urlVars; varLoad.load( urlRequest );
            varLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thankYou );
        }
    }
    function reset(e:MouseEvent):void {
        init(); //call the initial clear function
    }
    function checkEmail(s:String):Boolean {
        //This tests for correct email address
        var p:RegExp = /(\w|[_.\-])+@((\w|-)+\.)+\w{2,4}+/;
        var r:Object = p.exec(s);
        if( r == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   
    function thankYou(e:Event):void { 
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target); 
        var sent = new URLVariables(loader.data).sentStatus;
        if( sent == "yes" ) {
            valid.text = "Thanks for your email!"; timer = new Timer(500);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, msgSent);
            timer.start();
        }
        else {
            valid.text = "Something went wrong, please try again";
        }
    }

    function msgSent(te:TimerEvent):void {
        if(timer.currentCount >= 10) {
        init();
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, msgSent);
    }
```

*PHP file for mail processing:*

```
<?php
    $yourName = $_POST['name'];
    $fromEmail = $_POST['from'];
    $yourSubject = $_POST['subject'];
    $yourMsg = $_POST['msg'];

    if( $yourName == true ) {
        $sender = $fromEmail;
        $yourEmail ="myemailaddress@example.com"; // Naturally I put in my own email address here :)
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // This gets the user's ip Address

        $emailMsg = "Van: $sender\r\n" .
                    "Naam: $yourName\r" .
                    "Subject: my site - $yourSubject\n\n" .
                    "$yourMsg\n\n\n\n" .
                    "------------------------------\r" .
                    "Verstuurd vanaf IP-adres $ipAddress\r" .
                    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $return = "From: $sender\r\n";

        if( mail( $yourEmail, "$yourSubject", $emailMsg, $return)) { 
            echo "sentStatus=yes";
        }
        else {
            echo "sentStatus=no";
        }
    }
?>
```

### EDIT:

I have managed to resolve the Android issue on this. Safari still won't let me type.

I changed the title - ***Original question:*** "Flash form on Android lets me type only capital letters/CAPS, safari won't let me type at all"

The part that probably did the trick for Android was setting the textfields to be for `.htmlText` instead of `.text` in the AS3 code.

Comment: Lesson to be learned; stop making websites in Flash!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would suggest, is to see if you need to update your Flash version. I have seen an issue before where I couldn't type in Firefox and updating Flash resolved it.

Comment: I have the most recent version installed. But visitors of the site who have less recent versions (although not too old of course), should be able to use the form as well.