# Android browser does not accept characters in input text even though the charset is set

Tags: android, html, character-encoding

I have a webpage which specifies meta-charset to be iso-8859-1 and in the form for an input text also specifies accept-charset to the same. On each letter an ajax request is fired off, it works fine in all browsers except androids browser. There it just doesnt enter any special letters in iso-8859-1 such as åäö. What is the cause of this?

Comment: I recently asked a similar question concerning a Flash form, which might be interesting to keep track to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716394/safari-wont-let-me-type-in-flash-form I'm not sure if your question and mine are due to the same problem source though.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with my cyanogenmod :/ @poepje

Comment: Hm no idea what you're talking about, but it's probably a different thing then :p

Comment: I tested with a friends vanilla nonrooted android and it worked fine, which is to say my rooted phone is messing up :) but Ive seen many people have similar issues on many places while investigating this.